# Deleting row in table with merged cells if first cell is empty or with specific value

Tags: vba, ms-word, delete-row

I have excel file with data from where i merge information with different word files using mysql (Mailings).
In word documents i have tables, rows of which should be removed / deleted depending from the situation.

I found very useful macros, which scan all the tables in the word document, including tables with merged cells. And, if the whole row is empty (no data), macros delete the row.
But there are a lot of useless data in the cells, which is constant and not reflecting in excel for merging. only data in the first cell of the row is variable and enough to be used to decide regarding the row faith, to be delete or not.

below is the code. How to change the condition from whole empty row to first cell empty to delete the row?

```
Sub ClearEmptyRowsInTables 'чистилка таблиц
  Dim tb, tCells, ii, rPre, RowIsEmpty
 
  For Each tb In ActiveDocument.Tables 'переберём все таблицы
    Set tCells = tb.Range.Cells ' массив всех ячеек этой таблицы
    rPre = 0: RowIsEmpty = False 'начальные установки: предыдущий Row = 0 и он не пустой
    For ii = tCells.Count To 1 Step -1 'перебираем ячейки в обратном порядке
      If tCells(ii).RowIndex <> rPre Then ' если строка этой ячейки не совпадает со строкой ранее проверенной
        If RowIsEmpty Then 'если ранее проверенная строка пустая
          tCells(ii + 1).Range.Rows.Delete 'удалим её
        End If
        rPre = tCells(ii).RowIndex 'сохраняем строку текущей ячейки как проверяемую
        RowIsEmpty = False 
        If tCells(ii).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then RowIsEmpty = True 'проверяем текущую ячейку на пустоту
      Else 'если это та же строка - 
        If RowIsEmpty Then ' и она ещё пустая - проверим текущую ячейку и поменяем признак пустоты строки, если надо
          If tCells(ii).Range.Text <> Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then RowIsEmpty = False
        End If
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, r As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For Each Tbl In .Tables
    With Tbl
      For r = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        With .Rows(r)
          If Split(.Cells(1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "" Then .Delete
        End With
      Next
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

The code above works just fine with horizontally-merged cells. For a table with vertically-merged cells, you could use something like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, Rng As Range, r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, j As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For Each Tbl In .Tables
    With Tbl.Range
      For c = .Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        With .Cells(c)
          If .ColumnIndex = 1 Then
            If Split(.Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "" Then
              Set Rng = .Range: r = .RowIndex: i = c
              With Tbl.Range
                For j = i To .Cells.Count
                  If .Cells(j).RowIndex = r Then
                    Rng.End = .Cells(j).Range.End
                  Else
                    Exit For
                  End If
                Next
              End With
              With Rng
                .End = .End + 1
                .Rows.Delete
              End With
            End If
          End If
        End With
      Next
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

If your cell has some default text, simply insert that between the double quotes.

Comment: Hi,
First of all, thank you for your effort 
Sorry my knowledge in VBA is quite poor. There is some mistake -->>
If Split.Cells(1).Range.Text, vbCr)
outcome message Expected Then or GoTo after coma, and as I see there is an extra parenthesis or there should be one more parenthesis.
to be on a safe side, first cells of a rows are not merged or split. There are just some cells in the table are merged, which are not taking action in data change

Comment: Typo. Corrected.

Comment: thank you for correction actions, but, any way, there are more mistakes. -->
"If Split.Cells(1).Range.Text," if we use "," (coma) after Text - arise message that there should be "goto" or "then", i suppose we need to change "," to "<". But, when i do so, there come next message --> "Split" marked yellow and --> argument not optional

Comment: A '(' disappeared from the code. Corrected.

Comment: sorry, but i have to ask you one more time. There is error run time 5991 (cannot access individual rows in this collection in this collection because the table has vertically merged cells). As I Mentioned above, in my tables, merged cells are present, as i understood from some manuals I've read, we need to use Range instead of Table, but unfortunately, i have know idea how to use it correctly.

Comment: The previous code works just fine with horizontally-merged cells. You didn't say they were vertically-merged. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteRowsThatHaveAnyEmptyCellInAllTables() 'чистилка таблиц
  Dim tb, tCells, ii, rPre, RowHaveEmptyCell
 
  For Each tb In ActiveDocument.Tables 'переберём все таблицы
    Set tCells = tb.Range.Cells ' массив всех ячеек этой таблицы
    rPre = 0: RowHaveEmptyCell = False 'начальные установки: предыдущий Row = 0 и он не пустой
    For ii = tCells.Count To 1 Step -1 'перебираем ячейки в обратном порядке
      If tCells(ii).RowIndex <> rPre Then ' если № строки этой ячейки не совпадает с № строки, ранее проверенной
        If RowHaveEmptyCell Then 'если ранее проверенная строка содержит хоть одну пустую ячейку
          tCells(ii + 1).Range.Rows.Delete 'удалим её
        End If
        rPre = tCells(ii).RowIndex 'сохраняем строку текущей ячейки как проверяемую
        RowHaveEmptyCell = False
        If tCells(ii).Range.Text = Chr(160) & Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then RowHaveEmptyCell = True 'проверяем текущую ячейку на пустоту
      Else 'если это та же строка -
        If Not RowHaveEmptyCell Then ' и она ещё помечена как имеющая пустую ячейку - проверим текущую ячейку 
          If tCells(ii).Range.Text = Chr(160) & Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then RowHaveEmptyCell = True 'и поменяем признак наличия пустой
        End If
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```